# Java: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I run my Java program and my program does what it's supposed to, but prints the following error message: "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
"

What do I have to do to suppress it?